# No back button on segue in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swift2, ios9

I just ported my project over to Swift 2, and everything is working great - except that even the most simple segues have no back button.  Here is the prepare for segue function that I am using:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "showExercise" {
        if let nav = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
            if let exercisesController = nav.topViewController as? ExercisesController {
                let cell = sender as! WorkoutCell
                if let workout = cell.name!.text {
                    exercisesController.exercises = Workouts[workout]!
                    exercisesController.navigationItem.title = workout
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before, the back button to the parent segue used to automatically populate.  Now, all I get is the title in the child navigation vc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using show or show detail segue? It seems like you are using a modal segue. Destination view controller for show or show segue is usually the second view controller itself, and not embedded in another `UINavigationController`.

If your destination view controller for the show segue is really a `UINavigationController`, the new navigation controller's navigation bar settings may override the old one (the navigation controller of the source view controller). Try not embedding your destination view controller in another `UINavigationController`.

Comment: That seemed to be the issue!  Removing the `segue.destinationViewController` from it's own `UINavigationController` worked.  Cheers!

FWIW I was using a `Show (e.g. Push)`

Comment: @cadlac could you post the code that worked as an answer? I don't understand how your fix worked without breaking other code.