# Back button disappears on show segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I've read several posts about this issue, but I've been troubleshooting and the previous [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961247/no-back-button-on-segue-in-swift-2) don't seem to do the trick (i.e. the solutions specify **embedding only the parent controller in the navigation controller, which I've tried**). To address it as per previous posts, I've removed the embedding of the other views in their own navigation controllers -- but can't then seem to physically draw the segue from one table view to another; or it doesn't show the back button...

Basically, the "Back" button disappears on segue. It isn't seen in the second TableViewController and the last ViewController (on the end). It reappears in the parent, obviously.

[image: Storyboard Image]

EDIT: When I remove the navigation controller from the other two views, then no navigation bar appears on those VCs at all. The bar completely disappears, although it appears on the first one. This is how I have it configured now.

[New Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMcGv.png)

Comment: You don't have to embed each controller in Navigation Controller. That's why the back button is not being shown. Delete all the navigation controllers except of first one, set the proper connections and your 'Back' button will appear. Embedding only the parent controller in the navigation controller is the solution. If it didn't work for you, then you must have done something wrong.

The reason of button not showing is that you make a new navigation which basically means there will no be way back starting at this point.

Comment: I've tried that. While it all segues okay, now the entire navigation bar at the top has disappeared on the other views (aside from the parent view). I added the segue between the table view cell of one controller to the other table view, as it wouldn't let me add any other connections between the two controllers.

Comment: Which type of segue do you specify?

Comment: Adaptive segue, show detail. Changing it to push doesn't change anything either, although it does show the navigation bar in the Storyboard.

Comment: Try changing it to 'Show'. Show detail is used mostly for UISplitViewController and push is deprecated.

Comment: I've done that. It shows the navigation bar in the Storyboard, but when I run it in the Simulator, it still doesn't show up.

Comment: Did you change all the segues to 'Show'? The segue that comes from Navigation Controller should be 'Root view controller.' If all of above is okay, then you must have messed up the properties of either controllers or segues. Try re-creating all the windows and connections.

Comment: Yeah, all of the above is OK. I'll try recreating everything.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation Controller follows the [Stack theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). When you push something in the stack it will increment the top index count by 1 and pop something in the stack it will decrease the top index count by 1.

In the navigation controller, first controller will be your root viewController. Now When you push new view controller in navigation controller, your top index count will be 2. But you are not pushing the viewController in same navigation controller (let say Stack1) you are creating the new Navigation controller (let say Stack2).

So here you are setting the new controller as the root viewController for new navigation controller(Stack2) and there are no item to pop yet that is why it's not showing the back button.

To Solve these Problem remove the navigation controller from the second and third view controller.

To push you can use segue or you can do it programmatically.

**Swift**

```
let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as? ViewController2
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2!, animated: true)
```

**Objective C**

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

[Navigation Controller Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html)

**Edit**
if you are not able to see the navigation bar on second VC

1. Make sure you are not hiding it by code in second VC.
2. Make sure you are pushing the second VC not presenting the VC.
3. Select VC in Interface Builder -> Attribute Inspector -> Top bar should be inferred.
4. if you are using segue then segue type(kind) should be `Show`.

Comment: 'Push' is deprecated since iOS 8.

Comment: And also, the question specifies Swift programming language.

Comment: @T.Pasichnyk please check Swift code if it correct and thanks.